# Mysql query syntax for multiple conditions in select

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone I am having trouble with mysql query select syntax

```
WHERE ((a.product_id = b.product_id) AND (b.category_id = '20') AND (a.product_publish = '1') AND ( a.product_manufacturer_id = 2 ) AND (a.extra_field_10 = 92 ) AND (a.product_price BETWEEN 171 AND 631 ))
```

do you see any problem here?? (maybe missing quotes)

```
category_id (integer)
product_publish (integer)
extra_field_10  (integer)
product_price (integer)
manu (integer)
```

if you ask why are there brackets they are here because of multiple conditions like

```
WHERE ((a.product_id = b.product_id) AND (b.category_id = '20' || b.category_id = '21') AND (a.product_publish = '1') AND ( a.product_manufacturer_id = 2 ) AND (a.extra_field_10 = 92 || a.extra_field_10 = 11 ) AND (a.product_price BETWEEN 171 AND 631 ))
```

SELECT is correct
FROM is correct too 
values are correct it has to be syntax problem which i am missing

UPDATED ***************

- there are no errors sql just return false
- i know brackters are not neccesary but also they dont make errors
- columns are ok i am using similar selects and they work ok but this one cant work right

UPDATED ******************************

looks like there has to be problem somwhere else i will update this post when i figure out real problem maybe it could help someone in the future

Comment: please post your table structure

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You don't need any of these () ²

Comment: Why you use string literals to compare with integer?

Comment: Is `b.category_id` and `a.product_publish` strings or numbers?

Comment: Why you think the query is not work right? Can you provide the test data on which it must work right but not work?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need so many parenthesis in your code. It would be interesting also you post your table in http://sqlfiddle.com/. 
I believe this query (if all the fields in your query exist) will work. 
ps: If a field is integer you do not need quotes provided.

```
WHERE a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.category_id = 20 AND a.product_publish = 1
AND product_manufacturer_id = 2  AND a.extra_field_10 = 92 AND a.product_price BETWEEN 171 AND 631
```